# Rename columns using function input in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I know there are many similar questions regarding renaming columns in R, but I still have not found an elegant way to achieve this simple task, which can be easily done in Python.

Here is a simple function to convert GIS dataframe into Spatial Points. But first I want to rename coordinate columns into "lon" and "lat". Some data labels them "X" and "Y", while other may call "long" and "lat". So I want users to specify what were column names for "lon" and "lat". I am using `dplyr`. However, following will not work.

```
library("magrittr")
library("tidyverse")
ToSpatialPoint <- function(data, lon_col="long",lat_col="lati"){
    data %<>% rename(lon=lon_col,lat=lat_col) %<>% distinct(lon,lat) %<>% filter(!is.na(lon),!is.na(lat))
    processed_pts <- SpatialPoints(coords=cbind(lon=data$lon,lat=data$lat), proj4string = CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
    return(processed_pts)
}
```

I receive this error:

```
Error: `lon_col`, `lat_col` contains unknown variables
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to find a way to give specific names to a dataframe with two columns? And that you can't find an easy way to do that?

Comment: You need to load `dplyr` to use pipes unless you load `magrittr` separately, referencing a namespace won't let you use pipes. Also, you're calling a `plyr` function in your example, and you tag `dplyr` in your question, which do you actually want to use?

Comment: Try `%>%` instead

Comment: Also, if the actual thing you want to solve is to change the names of your columns, there's no need to involve extra code and functions like `SpatialPoints` that make your question more complicated with no reason :)

Comment: @anotherfred, thanks for your comments, but the pipe is not the problem. I edited the post to include the library.

Comment: @Mako212, I am fine with either library, but both `rename` in `plyr` and `dplyr` do not work me. I added  `plyr` tag.

Comment: You replied to the wrong person. The pipe you intend is presumably %>% not %<>%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I figured out the answer myself thanks to a link shared by my awesome roommate. 
[This document](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) from tidyverse.org explains how to program with `dplyr`. In particular, how to take function inputs and evaluate them in `dplyr`.

Following is the code that will work:

```
ToSpatialPoint <- function(data,lon_col="long",lat_col="lati"){
  lon_col <- enquo(lon_col)
  lat_col <- enquo(lat_col)
  data <– data %>% rename(lon=!!lon_col,lat=!!lat_col)
  return(data)
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer didn't work for me, but luckily I remembered the "Assignment by reference" operator, which is:

`:=`

-->

`rename(new_variable_name := old_variable_name)`

The package data.table has good documentation about it [in this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html).

In dplyr you will have to wrap the variable name you are passing with `sym` and `!!` (help on `!!` is under `??rlang::quotation`). Your new rename function should look like:

```
data %>%
  rename(!!sym(lon_col) := lon,
         !!sym(lat_col) := lat)
```

Comment: So does this require `library("data.table")`?  I am not sure why mine did not work for you, but glad you found this solution.

Comment: No this doesn't require the data.table package. I linked to its documentation because it's pretty thorough.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example, note that the new name goes on the left, and the current name goes on the right. You also don't need `c()` or quotes.

```
require(dplyr) 

mtcars %>% rename(miles_per_gallon=mpg, horsepower=hp)

                  miles_per_gallon cyl disp horsepower drat    wt  qsec vs am
Mazda RX4                     21.0   6  160        110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1
Mazda RX4 Wag                 21.0   6  160        110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1
Datsun 710                    22.8   4  108         93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1
Hornet 4 Drive                21.4   6  258        110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0
Hornet Sportabout             18.7   8  360        175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0
Valiant                       18.1   6  225        105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0
```

Using your example:

```
data %>% dplyr::rename(lon = lon_col, lat = lat_col)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need bang-bang (`!!`) to unquote a character variable. You also need to use a special substitute `:=` operator:

```
new <- "test"
old <- "Sepal.Length"
iris %>% 
  rename(!!new := Sepal.Length) %>% names
[1] "test"         "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width" 
[5] "Species" 

iris %>% 
  rename(!!new := !!old) %>% names
[1] "test"         "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width" 
[5] "Species" 

testf <- function(old, new) {
  iris %>% rename(!!new := !!old)
}
testf(old, new) %>% names
[1] "test"         "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width" 
[5] "Species"
```